# Made a program but keep getting ')' , ';' , and illegal start of expression errors? (java)

Tags: java, arrays, directory

I had to make a program that takes in a text file called directory and I have 2 classes. Class directory contains all the possible operations such as add a name, check to see if a name exists, delete a name, and then write the updated directory back to the text file. Class DirectoryWithObjectDesign has the main method, opens the directory, handles user interaction, and closes the directory when done.

Here is Class DirectoryWithObjectDesign:

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class DirectoryWithObjectDesign {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   String directoryDataFile  = "Directory.txt";
   Directory d = new Directory(directoryDataFile);
   Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Directory Server is Ready!");
   System.out.println("Format: command name");
   System.out.println("Enter ^Z to end");
   while (stdin.hasNext()) {
      String command = stdin.next();
      String name = stdin.next();
      if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("find")) {
         if (d.inDirectory(name))
            System.out.println(name + " is in the directory");
         else 
            System.out.println(name + " is NOT in the directory");
      }
      else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {
         if (d.add(name))
            System.out.println(name + " added");
         else 
            System.out.println(name + " cannot add! " + "no more space or already in directory");
      }
      else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")) {
         if (d.delete(name))
            System.out.println(name + " deleted");
         else
            System.out.println(name + " NOT in directory");
      }
      else {
         System.out.println("bad command, try again");
      }
   }
   }
}
```

And here is Class directory

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Directory {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   final int maxDirectorySize = 1024;
   String directory[] = new String[maxDirectorySize];
   int directorySize = 0;
   File directoryFile = null;
   Scanner directoryDataIn = null;
   Directory(String directoryFileName) {
      directoryFile = new File(directoryFileName);
      try {
         directoryDataIn = new Scanner(directoryFile);
      }
      catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         System.out.println("File is not found, exiting!", 
                           directoryFileName);
         System.exit(0);
      }
      while (directoryDataIn.hasNext()) {
         directory[directorySize++] = directoryDataIn.nextLine();
      }
   public boolean inDirectory(String name) {
      for (int i = 0; i < directory.length; i++) {
         if (directory[i].equalsIgnoreCase(name)) 
            return true;
         else 
            return false;
      }
   }
   public boolean add(String name) {
      if (directory.length == 1024)
         return false;
      for (int i = 0; i < directory.length; i++) {
         if (directory[i].equalsIgnoreCase(name))
            return false;
         else
            directory[directorySize++] = name;
            return true;
      }
   }          

   public boolean delete(String name) {
      for (int i = 0; i < directory.length; i++) {
         if (directory[i].equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            directory[i] = null;
            return true;
         }   
         else
            return false;
      }
   }

   public void closeDirectory() {
      directoryDataIn.close();
      PrintStream driectoryDataOut = null;
      try {
         directoryDataOut = new PrintStream(directoryFile);
      }
      catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         System.out.printf("File %s not found, exiting!", directoryFile);
         System.exit(0);
      }
      String originalDirectory[] = {"Mike","Jim","Barry","Cristian","Vincent","Chengjun","susan","ng","serena"};
      if (originalDirectory == directory)
         System.exit(0);
      else
         for (int i = 0; i < directorySize; i++)
            directoryDataOut.println(directory[i]);
         directoryDataOut.close();
   }
}
```

these are the errors when i try running DirectoryWithObjectDesign

```
Directory.java:10: error: ')' expected
   Directory(String directoryFileName) {
                   ^
Directory.java:10: error: illegal start of expression
   Directory(String directoryFileName) {
                                     ^
Directory.java:10: error: ';' expected
   Directory(String directoryFileName) {
                                      ^
Directory.java:23: error: illegal start of expression
   public boolean inDirectory(String name) {
   ^
Directory.java:23: error: ';' expected
   public boolean inDirectory(String name) {
                             ^
Directory.java:23: error: ';' expected
   public boolean inDirectory(String name) {
                                         ^
Directory.java:31: error: illegal start of expression
   public boolean add(String name) {
   ^
Directory.java:31: error: ';' expected
   public boolean add(String name) {
                     ^
Directory.java:31: error: ';' expected
   public boolean add(String name) {
                                 ^
Directory.java:43: error: illegal start of expression
   public boolean delete(String name) {
   ^
Directory.java:43: error: ';' expected
   public boolean delete(String name) {
                        ^
Directory.java:43: error: ';' expected
   public boolean delete(String name) {
                                    ^
Directory.java:54: error: illegal start of expression
   public void closeDirectory() {
   ^
Directory.java:54: error: illegal start of expression
   public void closeDirectory() {
          ^
Directory.java:54: error: ';' expected
   public void closeDirectory() {
                             ^
Directory.java:72: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
 ^
DirectoryWithObjectDesign.java:6: error: constructor Directory in class Directory cannot be applied to given types;
   Directory d = new Directory(directoryDataFile);
                 ^
  required: no arguments
  found: String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
DirectoryWithObjectDesign.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
         if (d.inDirectory(name))
              ^
  symbol:   method inDirectory(String)
  location: variable d of type Directory
DirectoryWithObjectDesign.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
         if (d.add(name))
              ^
  symbol:   method add(String)
  location: variable d of type Directory
DirectoryWithObjectDesign.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
         if (d.delete(name))
              ^
  symbol:   method delete(String)
  location: variable d of type Directory
Directory.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
   Directory(String directoryFileName) {
             ^
  symbol:   variable String
  location: class Directory
Directory.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
      directoryFile = new File(directoryFileName);
                               ^
  symbol:   variable directoryFileName
  location: class Directory
Directory.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
                           directoryFileName);
                           ^
  symbol:   variable directoryFileName
  location: class Directory
Directory.java:26: error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
            return true;
                   ^
Directory.java:28: error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
            return false;
                   ^
Directory.java:31: error: variable name is already defined in method main(String[])
   public boolean add(String name) {
                             ^
Directory.java:33: error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
         return false;
                ^
Directory.java:36: error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
            return false;
                   ^
Directory.java:39: error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
            return true;
                   ^
Directory.java:43: error: variable name is already defined in method main(String[])
   public boolean delete(String name) {
                                ^
Directory.java:47: error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
            return true;
                   ^
Directory.java:50: error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
            return false;
                   ^
Directory.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
         directoryDataOut = new PrintStream(directoryFile);
         ^
  symbol:   variable directoryDataOut
  location: class Directory
Directory.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
            directoryDataOut.println(directory[i]);
            ^
  symbol:   variable directoryDataOut
  location: class Directory
Directory.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
         directoryDataOut.close();
         ^
  symbol:   variable directoryDataOut
  location: class Directory
35 errors
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: At what line does the error occur?

Comment: Compile time error or runtime error?

Comment: The constructor in your Directory class is within the main method. That is not allowed.

Comment: @savic Like @assylias said you shouldn't have your constructor inside your main method also you shouldn't have other methods in your main method like `add()` `inDirectory()` etc...Methods should be in the class scope not in another method scope.

Comment: The errors are everywhere. I just updated the post with all the errors. I've never done anything like this before so I'm going crazy trying to fix them.. when i change one thing, several more errors appear!

Comment: I fixed this error just now...but i'm still getting these ')' and ';' expected errors..

Comment: @savic look at my answer try copying and pasting my answer into your Directory class it should fix most of your errors...

Comment: @brso05 now I got 19 cannot find symbol errors when I try to run the Directory class. When i try to run the DirectoryWithObjectDesign class, I get this message

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Directory
 at DirectoryWithObjectDesign.main(DirectoryWithObjectDesign.java:6)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Directory
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)

Comment: @savic you probably don't want to run your `Directory` class it is just a helper class for your main class `DirectoryWithObjectDesign` (I think that's what you want?)...

Comment: So it's normal to get errors in the Directory class? And what should I do about the exception in thread "main"? I tried seeing if removing throws IOexception would do anything but nope.. @brso05

Comment: @savic no it's not normal you should correct any errors that are left...

Answer (score 1):

One mistake is in this line:

```
System.out.println("File is not found, exiting!", 
                       directoryFileName);
```

`System.out.println()` only accepts one argument.
Apart from that it would be helpful if you mark where the error
occurs.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is after the `Scanner directoryDataIn = null;`.

There's something like a constructor: `Directory(String directoryFileName) {`

Constructors must be put in the class and not in the main method.(And also other methods declarations)

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your constructor and methods outside the main method like so:

```
public class Directory {
    final int maxDirectorySize = 1024;
    String directory[] = new String[maxDirectorySize];
    int directorySize = 0;
    File directoryFile = null;
    Scanner directoryDataIn = null;

    public Directory(String directoryFileName) {
      directoryFile = new File(directoryFileName);
      try {
         directoryDataIn = new Scanner(directoryFile);
      }
      catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         System.out.println("File is not found, exiting!" + 
                           directoryFileName);
         System.exit(0);
      }
      while (directoryDataIn.hasNext()) {
         directory[directorySize++] = directoryDataIn.nextLine();
      }
    }

    public boolean inDirectory(String name) {
        for (int i = 0; i < directory.length; i++) {
            if (directory[i].equalsIgnoreCase(name))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean add(String name) {
        if (directory.length == 1024)
            return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < directory.length; i++) {
            if (directory[i].equalsIgnoreCase(name))
                return false;
            else
                directory[directorySize++] = name;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean delete(String name) {
        for (int i = 0; i < directory.length; i++) {
            if (directory[i].equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                directory[i] = null;
                return true;
            } else
                return false;
        }
    }

    public void closeDirectory() {
        directoryDataIn.close();
        PrintStream driectoryDataOut = null;
        try {
            directoryDataOut = new PrintStream(directoryFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.printf("File %s not found, exiting!", directoryFile);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        String originalDirectory[] = { "Mike", "Jim", "Barry", "Cristian",
                "Vincent", "Chengjun", "susan", "ng", "serena" };
        if (originalDirectory == directory)
            System.exit(0);
        else
            for (int i = 0; i < directorySize; i++)
                directoryDataOut.println(directory[i]);
        directoryDataOut.close();
    }
}
```

That should fix most of your errors...